# Avoid reading from the past with "read" command

Tags: bash

I don't know how to say that, but here is an example :

```
read -n1 key;sleep 5;read -n1 key
```

If you launch this and press two keys (let's say 'a' and 'b') during the execution of the first "read", the first "read" capture the 'a' as expected but 5 seconds later the 'b' is automatically captured by the second "read".

How to avoid this, and "read" input only after the sleep command ?

Comment: flush stdin after each read

Comment: @Drako As per C standard, it is undefined behavior to use fflush(stdin). How you do flushing a stream in bash is an enigma shrouded in mystery.

Comment: I've got something like this to work, but is it the best answer ? `read -n 1 key;sleep 2;read -e -t 0.1;read -n 1 key`

Comment: @bobdylan the best answer is "just don't do that, it's counterintuitive and will annoy users that routinely type ahead".

Comment: That's exactly the purpose of this question : I don't want user to type ahead.

Comment: @n.m.but this question makes me guess bash in not the language for this task too - looks like kind of corner-case or wrong tool or something

Comment: Have you asked the users what *they* want?

Comment: Thank you for the concern, but it is not up to debate.

Comment: Do whatever you want, good luck. `read -t 0.1` is not enough. First, discarded characters will be echoed, you want to suppress that, use `read` with `-s` flag. Second, `read` will only read one line, you want a while loop here.

Comment: [Duplicate](https://superuser.com/questions/276531/clear-stdin-before-reading)